# webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: not always triggered

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiwebview, webview

As can be seen in the screencast below, I'm having a devil of a time getting webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: to be called consistently.

In the screencast below, you'll see a UIWebview with three size selectors.  When clicking on any of these three, webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: *should* be getting triggered.  Unfortunately, that doesn't always seem to be happening.  It doesn't event seem to happen consistently.

http://screencast.com/t/ww6uwP1Je

So what's causing this?  Is there an error method of UIWebViewDelegate that I could hook into to pick up some of what's going on internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out I didn't provide anyone enough information for anyone to answer the question - I even removed the relevant parts from the webview gist given above.  Sorry!

Here's the full template:

https://gist.github.com/521d17e0377133725d9a

Turns out there was an onclick handler on the li surounding the link (see the gist above - "#sizes_slider li").  Removing that onclick handler did the trick.

Comment: Just to clarify, the problem was in the HTML of the page and not the WebView's code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you aren't setting the UIWebViewDelegate properly.  I noticed in the screencast that it worked once you clicked the 'L' (presumedly "large") button.  Is that method setting the delegate?  If not, please paste a code snippet that shows the issue.

Comment: Hopefully, his delegate isn't being assigned based on the button pushed in a page. The delegate belongs to the web view itself and not any random page.

Comment: The delegate is assigned in the xib.  I never set it directly in code.

Comment: Here's a code sample of the relevant code.  It's a webview that's loaded from a mustache template:  https://gist.github.com/aebb903b13a6e44631a2  The links are triggered and the delegate is never touched with code.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other two buttons generate calls to the delegate we know your web view delegate is properly assigned.

The simplest explanation for the failure is that `S` button is not configured in HTML properly and does not generate a actual request for the web view to load. With no request, the delegate methods are never called in the first place.

Comment: Actually, if you notice - later on in the video the 'S' button does work!